# Filter in Filter function Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

I have a Sheet with the prices of some products
Each column is a parameter.

How to use the `FILTER()` function in order to filter by multiple conditions

In this case I need to filter and see only the rows where the `Power=I3` and the `Manufacturer=I2`, I am sure that I have to use the `FILTER(FILTER() f`

This is what I managed to create:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(A2:F,B2:B=I3),D2:D=I2)
```

but it returns the following error :

> Error `FILTER` has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: `7`. column
>   count: `1`. Actual row count: `999`, column count: `1`.

---

**UPDATE**:
I managed to do it with

```
=FILTER(A2:F,IF(ISBLANK(A2),1,A2:A=A2)*IF(ISBLANK(D2),1,D2:D=D2))
```

But it becomes too long and not elegant. I am sure that there is a better way to do it.

Especially if I want to create more conditions for each column....
[image]

Comment: @pjmg [tag:google-sheets-filter], according to it's tag excerpt and wiki, it is for questions about using the UI filter and filter view feature

Comment: Okay, I'll be more careful when I add tags to my edits. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The "elegant" way to use `FILTER` to filter `A2:F`  where `B2:B` (Power) `=I3` and `D2:D` (Manufacturer) `=I2` is

```
=FILTER(A2:F,B2:B=I4,D2:D=I3)
```

The above works because filter allow multiple criteria arguments.

Reference

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately when some of the criteria is not set it still filters the results and returns N/A.

Any idea how to fix it?